# VB6 - Making a console application Arguments?

Tags: vb6

it's very unclear on vb6 on how to actually do this does anybody actually know how this might be done?

thanks everybody, I really do appreciate this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, I have no idea what you're asking. Can you [edit] your question to make it more clear and add some details? Thanks.

Comment: this may be your answer: http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?337778-Passing-in-Command-Line-Arguments-VB6

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152562/exe-with-accepting-runtime-parameter

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim cmdargs() As String

cmdargs = Split(Command$, "/")
For x = 1 To UBound(cmdargs)
    MsgBox "Argument " & x & " = " & cmdargs(x)
Next
```

Pass arguments to exe:

```
Hello.exe /this /is /an /example
```

This will show 4 message boxes:

Argument 1 = this

Argument 2 = is

Argument 3 = an

Argument 4 = example